# ::GetPrivateProfileString read whole section of INI file

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, configuration-files, ini

I'm modifying existing C++ application and moving out some values that are currently hard coded.

I'm doing this with one class that will "manage" this whole thing and hold `map<CString, CString>` of the values from the INI file.

Right now I have to read each value separately using `::GetPrivateProfileString` function  - can I somehow read whole section instead of single value?

Prefer not to have to read the file manually, but if there's any reasonable (i.e. efficient + simple to use) existing way I'm open for suggestions.

Edit: just now had to use it "for real" and the solution was indeed passing NULL as the *lpKeyName* value. Complete code including parsing the return value:

```
char buffer[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
int charsCount = ::GetPrivateProfileString("MySection", NULL, NULL, buffer, MAX_STRING_SIZE, m_strIniPath);
CString curValue;
curValue.Empty();
char curChar = '\0';
for (int i = 0; i < charsCount; i++)
{
    curChar = buffer[i];
    if (curChar == '\0')
    {
        if (curValue.GetLength() > 0)
            HandleValue(curValue);
        curValue.Empty();
    }
    else
    {
        curValue.AppendFormat("%c", curChar);
    }
}
if (curValue.GetLength() > 0)
    HandleValue(curValue);
```

It's not trivial as it returns the keys separated by zero character (EOS?) so I had to extract them using loop such as the above - share it here for the sake of everyone who might need it. :-)

Comment: If it can be useful to you, once I wrote a class to manage a single INI section that works using `GetPrivateProfileSection` - you can have a look at it here (http://code.google.com/p/irfanpaint/source/browse/trunk/irfanpaint/INISection.h / http://code.google.com/p/irfanpaint/source/browse/trunk/irfanpaint/INISection.cpp); not the most beautiful or modern code I ever wrote, but it used to work fine. :)

Comment: @Matteo: thanks, I already have the code for parsing the values themselves. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to read the file manually but it helps to read the manual for [GetPrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> lpKeyName [in] : The name of the key
>   whose associated string is to be
>   retrieved. **If this parameter is NULL,
>   all key names in the section specified
>   by the lpAppName parameter are copied
>   to the buffer specified by the
>   lpReturnedString parameter**.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably consider the use of [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) (which provides a [INI parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.ini_parser)) :

> The Property Tree library provides a
>   data structure that stores an
>   arbitrarily deeply nested tree of
>   values, indexed at each level by some
>   key. Each node of the tree stores its
>   own value, plus an ordered list of its
>   subnodes and their keys. The tree
>   allows easy access to any of its nodes
>   by means of a path, which is a
>   concatenation of multiple keys.
>
> In addition, the library provides
>   parsers and generators for a number of
>   data formats that can be represented
>   by such a tree, including XML, INI,
>   and JSON.

Comment: Thanks, this looks more than what I need but I'll surely take a look. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at GetPrivateProfileSection? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724348(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I needed - feel stupid for not knowing about it myself!

Comment: Sorry just now had to use that code "for real" and that method is returning the whole section data while I need only the keys - Eugen answer is more accurate.