# How to use GetProfileSectionA to read INI section in C++

Tags: c++, buffer, ini

I'm attempting to read an entire section of an INI file using C++, but cannot find a good example on how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Check this question, perhaps it helps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4534048/220636)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this [GetPrivateProfileSection Link](http://vcpptips.wordpress.com/tag/getprivateprofilesection/)

you can try to get all the key and values for all the sections of an ini file.